# The referenced file is not allowed on this page O365 Sharepoint

Tags: master-page, custom-masterpage, system-master-page

I was trying to add script links to the seattle.master page in SharePoint 2013 from a network drive.

After I opened it (Before I added anything) I had to quit for the day. Now I keep getting this error

The referenced file '`/teams/site-Name/_catalogs/masterpage/seattle.master~RFa576ead.TMP'` is not allowed on this page.

In the masterpage folder there is now a .TMP file.

I can't find a reference to the file in the seattle.master and when I try to delete it it just comes back.

I can't load any pages on the site-Name because the same error shows up?

Has anyone ever run into this before?

Comment: did you made the copy of master page or you edit the curent master page?

Comment: I opened the master file but didn't edit it. I was just looking around. I might have saved a space or something.

Comment: Yes I had this when opening the file from visual studio. My solution was to stop doing that because it just became annoying xD

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but was able to find a way to fix it. You need to have SharePoint Designer installed and connected to your site. Once you do that, navigate to the Master Pages and set a different theme as your default. I had a problem with oslo.master, so I set seattle.master as my Default Master Page and was able to log onto my SharePoint site again. Then go into SiteSettings>MasterPages and blow away the .TMP file. Everything should work fine now.